# Interpreting Row Lock Contention in AWR Report

Tags: oracle, performance, awr

My AWR report shows the following :

```
Event                        Waits  Total Wait Time(s) 
enq: TX - row lock contention 30       10,694
```

Does 10,694 represents clock time ?

Or does it represents total time spent by all sessions which were monitored during the period AWR was generated ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the latter;  time spent by all sessions which were monitored during the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

It is the total suffered time of all the sessions which was suffered due to "TX-row lock contention".

Answer (score 0):

you have see wait stats is showing

[image]

see what queries are running on server.

[image]

**check blocking by :-**
select blocking_session, sid, serial#, wait_class, seconds_in_wait from v$session where blocking_session is not NULL order by blocking_session;

**SQL currently is waiting :-**
select sid, sql_text from v$session s, v$sql q where sid in (select sid from v$session where state in (‘WAITING’) and wait_class != ‘Idle’ and event=’enq: TX – row lock contention’ and (q.sql_id = s.sql_id or q.sql_id = s.prev_sql_id));